# Oracle:To realize the column automatic management

Tags: oracle, plsql

dataSource:

```
username type rank
a        106  1
a        116  2
a        126  3
b        106  1
b        106  2
```

when remove a,116,2  this record return:

```
username type rank
a        106  1
a        126  2
b        106  1
b        106  2
```

when insert a,116 return:

```
username type rank
a        106  1
a        126  2
a        116  3
b        106  1
b        106  2
```

I choose use tigger to realize:

insert(succeed):

```
create or replace trigger bi_auto
  before insert
  on auto 
  for each row
declare
  -- local variables here
begin
  select count(rank)+1 into :new.rank from auto where username=:new.username;
end bi_auto;
```

delete(fail,return ora-04091, ora-06512, ora-04088):

```
create or replace trigger bd_auto
  after delete
  on auto 
  for each row
declare
  -- local variables here
begin
  insert into session_auto
  select username, type, rank() over(partition by username order by rank) ranknew from auto where username=:old.username order by username;
  delete from auto where username=:old.username;
  insert into auto select * from session_auto;
end bd_auto;
```

Please help me to modify it,thanks.I know there is something wrong with the performance, but I want to know how to realize.

Answer (score 0):

I think the entire approach is problematic and error prone. It would be much easier to calculate the rank dynamically. If you want the convenience of querying a table, you could just add it to a view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW auto_view AS
SELECT username, type, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY username ORDER BY TYPE ASC) r
FROM   auto
```

If performance is **that** big of an issue, you could always [materialize your view](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96567/repmview.htm).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If use view, I have a problem when insert or delete.Example:When I delete `b,106,1` this record, I don't know if there is no rank which article to delete.

Comment: @zhanzezhu in insert/delete you only use username and type. rank is only a visual (hint for humans).